# WebView in Android - invisible but not null

Tags: android

If I change the visibility to invisible for WebView, will the webpage still be there? Or will it close the WebView page & reload when it's visible?
I want the webpage to still be there but invisible.

Answer (score 1):

If it is invisible, it will still be there. It will not have to reload when it becomes visible.

[INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) will make it invisible, but still take up layout space.

[GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) will make it invisible, and not take up layout space.

Neither should make the page reload when they become visible again.

Answer (score 0):

If its invisible, the WebView will still be there and act as normal while invisible. Making something invisible doesn't close it. More information on:

- [Android WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)
- [View (the class you use to set visibility)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Answer (score 0):

in the case of invisible the content is not visible to anyone but it stays at its own place in lay out
with the case of gone is also same we can not see it but the difference is it leaves its position lets other to have it visibility is provided

Comment: Some punctuation would be nice.